# Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked

Tags: angularjs

I have youtube urls in json file as `popup.bottom.url` and I need to show them on the page. However I can't because it seems that angular is not allowing that.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{popup.bottom.url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried using `trystAsResource` but it just shows empty `src` property ergo video is not shown. How can I achieve what I want?

#### What I have tried

- `src="{{trustAsResourceUrl('url', popup.bottom.url)}}"`
- `src="{{trustAsResourceUrl(popup.bottom.url)}}"`

Comment: Have you tried [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)?

Comment: Also, you're aware that `trustAsResourceUrl` is a function of the `$sce` provider right? Unless you're binding it to your scope, I wouldn't think that you could just call it directly from the DOM like that

Comment: @MarcKline Yes, same effect.

Comment: @Mike tried as `ng-src="{{$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('url',popup.bottom.url)}}` and `ng-src="{{$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(popup.bottom.url)}}` same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need indeed to "trust as resource-url". But `trustAsResourceUrl()` is a method of the `$sce` service (not defined on $scope), so you can't just use `src="{{trustAsResourceUrl(popup.bottom.url)}}"`.

You could alias it on the `$scope`, like this:

```
ng-src="{{trustAsResourceUrl}}"

.controller('...', function ($sce, $scope) {
    ...
    $scope.trustAsResourceUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl;
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/KVgMx/)**.